# Executing java from CLI via exec() under Windows

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface

I have a PHP-script originally developed on Ubuntu, which now has to run on a Windows machine, executing a java program like this:

```
exec("java -jar {$filename}");
// Process output
```

This does not work as expected on Windows. I already found out, that although I can use `java -version` from the command prompt I can't use it in `exec()`, i.e. the problem is java can not be found.

I have a workaround in place, pointing to java.exe using the complete path to `C:\Program Files\Java\...\java.exe` if the script runs on Windows. Unfortunately though this is hardcoded to the path on the current machine, which might change or vary on a different system, e.g. when installing Java to a different location or a different version (JRE/JDK/6/7) is installed.

**How do I call Java on Windows without having to refer to the exact location of java.exe?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set enviroment variable on windows, to be able access java without path

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: I know, and I have. In the Windows command prompt it is working from any directory, but with the PHP-script it is not wirking.

Comment: Silly me. It was the PATH-environment variable. As previously noted, I could call java in the command prompt and it still worked. I checked my PATH and it was set to a wrong directory (probably an old version).

Answer (score 0):

Even if this Question is a little older, I ran into the same problem and I found a pretty neat solution for it without the PATH requirement.

There is a symlinks to all java executabled located in this folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

for example: just call

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -jar XYZ.jar
```